# Webpack 3 Correct way of excluding a directory from bundle

Tags: webpack

I am looking for the correct way to exclude a specific folder from the webpack bundle.

My config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');

const config = {
  entry: [
    './client',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /./,
        exclude: /src/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [],
};
module.exports = config;
```

For my understanding this config should exclude the /src/ directory but instead webpack is keeping adding files to the bundle from this directory, because the test will match *any* and the exclude will affect any in src directory. Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it (if anyone else having the same issue)

With this code I exclude all files from bundle which are located in /src/server/*

```
  externals: [
    function excludeDir(context, request, callback) {
      if (/.src\/server./.test(path.resolve(context, request))) {
        return callback(null, 'commonjs');
      }
      return callback();
    },
  ],
```